# Searching, printing, incrementing, and outputting from a data set

Tags: python, string, file, search

I am struggling to find an efficient method of searching a file, then outputting a specific number of lines in that file. So let's say I have a file called "mc_coordinates" that I want to extract info from. It details the coordinates of atoms at a given "step". This file is organized such that it looks like:

```
         235
     INITIAL BOX 1, STEP 1
        C        12.7908790847        2.8828150218        1.1868087958
        F        11.8993427046        1.8104266120        1.3121312895
        F        13.8944796514        2.3931204072        0.4205213241
        H        12.2211496090        3.7216596131        0.7243429292
        H        13.2020314728        3.1740947812        2.1515988338
        C        12.7759828577        3.6624296172       15.2649736115
        F        11.9718262161        4.3758674409       16.1755975367
        F        12.3319038697        2.3994507343       15.0709447687
        H        12.7017245825        4.2254002044       14.2724601980
        H        13.8483690007        3.6371660190       15.6480138479
```

To clarify: INITIAL BOX (STEP NUMBER). At each "step", we record every atoms position. My problem is that I am only interested in steps that are in multiples of 48, because these are the coordinates that I am interested in observing. So, this means I must develop code that:

1) Finds 'INITIAL BOX 1'.

2) Take the line immediately before this INITAL BOX STEP # line, in this example, 235, and divides it by 5 and outputs this info

3) Prints every atoms coordinates starting with 'C' until I reach the lone number in the line prior to 'INITIAL BOX 2'

4) I then need to search my file again for "INITIAL BOX 49" and basically repeat step-2 taking the number, dividing by 5, outputting this info, and by printing/outputting all the coordinates until I reach the lone number before "INITIAL BOX 50".

This process repeats itself approximately 600 times. This is what I have so far:

```
 fo = open("mc_coordinates")
 lines = fo.readlines()
 for line in lines:
        print lines.find(INITIAL)
```

But this is giving me errors, and doesn't even begin to do the job that I require. Any tips or help would be appreciated! Thanks!
EDIT: SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
        47     # which is 235/5
        C        12.7908790847        2.8828150218        1.1868087958
        F        11.8993427046        1.8104266120        1.3121312895
        F        13.8944796514        2.3931204072        0.4205213241
        H        12.2211496090        3.7216596131        0.7243429292
        H        13.2020314728        3.1740947812        2.1515988338
        C        12.7759828577        3.6624296172       15.2649736115
        F        11.9718262161        4.3758674409       16.1755975367
        F        12.3319038697        2.3994507343       15.0709447687
        H        12.7017245825        4.2254002044       14.2724601980
        H        13.8483690007        3.6371660190       15.6480138479
```

@Bharadwa code yields:

```
  47.0
  C        12.7908790847        2.8828150218        1.1868087958
  F        11.8993427046        1.8104266120        1.3121312895
  F        13.8944796514        2.3931204072        0.4205213241
  H        12.2211496090        3.7216596131        0.7243429292
  H        13.2020314728        3.1740947812        2.1515988338
  C        12.7759828577        3.6624296172       15.2649736115
  F        11.9718262161        4.3758674409       16.1755975367
  F        12.3319038697        2.3994507343       15.0709447687
  H        12.7017245825        4.2254002044       14.2724601980
  H        13.8483690007        3.6371660190       15.6480138479
  BOX 1,  STEP 24
  C        12.4921773110        2.8286307659        1.1644437594
  F        11.6006113644        1.7562423561        1.2895557390
  F        13.5960941031        2.3384787776        0.3989045637
  H        11.9164523192        3.6676509395        0.7097873135
  H        12.9031018802        3.1199105253        2.1293308523
  C        12.4895445934        3.5818345553       14.9048344490
  F        11.6838031267        4.2949649016       15.8142975674
  F        12.0450334972        2.3193713672       14.7084532328
  H        12.4010184199        4.1124983940       13.8958289702
  H        13.5698640919        3.5405566993       15.2634094502
```

I need:

```
  47.0
  C        12.7908790847        2.8828150218        1.1868087958
  F        11.8993427046        1.8104266120        1.3121312895
  F        13.8944796514        2.3931204072        0.4205213241
  H        12.2211496090        3.7216596131        0.7243429292
  H        13.2020314728        3.1740947812        2.1515988338
  C        12.7759828577        3.6624296172       15.2649736115
  F        11.9718262161        4.3758674409       16.1755975367
  F        12.3319038697        2.3994507343       15.0709447687
  H        12.7017245825        4.2254002044       14.2724601980
  H        13.8483690007        3.6371660190       15.6480138479
  48.0
  BOX 1,  STEP 48
  C        12.6660795715        3.6355249989       15.1210670811
  F        11.9116309909        4.3486553452       16.0735112076
  F        12.2114308249        2.3730618108       14.9494564347
  H        12.5221365040        4.1661888376       14.1184657979
  H        13.7645020294        3.5942471429       15.4196208523
```

Comment: It is simple, basic text parsing. Let me put it this way, correct me if I am wrong, 1. Whenever I see a lonely number then I divide it by 5. 2. Print every line that starts with "c" after the INITIAL, keep continuing this till end of file?

Comment: you get some random numbers in the output because you are printing the position of the find. Moreover there is no variable called INITIAL

Comment: Not just "C" but every atomic position, including "F" and "H". I want every atomic coordinate after the "initial box" that I find relevant

Comment: May be I can help you if you explain me the steps in simple terms, I dont need info regarding why you need to display some data, but just tell me how you want the output to look like. Sample output is appreciated

Comment: What errors? `print lines.find(INITIAL)`? What do you expect it to do and why?

Comment: Ok I will edit my original post to provide sample output. Peter Woods, I get an error regarding that line.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I made the edit to show sample output. My file is too big to show on this site. After my program outputs this data for 'INITIAL BOX 1, STEP 1', I need it to search for 'INITIAL BOX 1, STEP 49', then show output in similar format. It should be noted that the number before 'Initial box' is the total number of atoms that we will be dealing with in that Box. Please ask if you are unclear on and I will do my best to explain

Answer (score 0):

The code snippets as per my understanding, there are 2 codes
1. All the atoms will be printed.
2. Prints those atoms that are multiples of `STEP` variable.
I guess the code 2 is more useful for your work

```
#[code1]

with open("mc_coordinates") as file:
    [print(str(float(line.strip())/5)) if len(line.split(' '))==1 else print(line.strip())
    for line in file if not line.strip().startswith('INITIAL')]
```

---

```
#[code2]

STEP = 48
Arr = []
newlines = []

with open("mc_coordinates") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('INITIAL'):
            continue
        if len(line.split(' '))==1:
            if Arr:
                newlines.append(Arr)
            Arr = []
            Arr.append(str(float(line)/5))
        else:
            Arr.append(line)

[print(j) for i, line in enumerate(newlines) for j in line if not i%STEP]
```

or replace the last line by the following code

```
for i, line in enumerate(newlines):
    for j in line:
        if not i%STEP:
            print(j)
```

Comment: File "stackover.py", line 18
    [print(j) for i, line in enumerate(newlines) for j in line if not i%STEP]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                            @Bharadwaj  I got this error. I am not familiar with the syntax in this line. Could you explain it a little ?

Comment: Are you using Python2.X or 3.X ??

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.5

Comment: Plz check the main post, I have added the lines

Comment: This is excellent work, although it is not quite what I expected. This lists everything by steps of 24, not 48.

Comment: Is there a private way of sending u this info

Comment: IT admin says no can do. The code is ok as is. Maybe you could explain the syntax, as I am unfamiliar with it. The output gives everything in terms of 24 steps, not 48. I will make an edit to show you an example of what your code is doing

Comment: Try STEP count as 96, if that doesnt work then it means I didnt understand the requirement perfectly